Significance of constant $k_e$ in electrostatic force
So recently I read that the magnitude of electrostatic force between two charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ is given by the expression
$$F = \frac{k_e q_1 q_2}{r^2}$$
where $r$ is the distance of separation between the charges, and $$k_e = \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}$$ and $\epsilon_0$ represents the permittivity of free space. As per my understanding, I think of permittivity of free space as a physical constant that reflects the ability of electrical fields to pass through a classical vacuum.
however, what exactly does the expression as a whole $\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}$ mean physically?
Here are my questions:

What exactly is the rationale behind $4\pi$ in this expression?

How was it exactly determined as a constant of proportionality? Was it through relatively simple methods like the one used in the Cavendish experiment for determining the value of $G$?



It would probably interest you to know that the coulomb constant only appears this way in certain unit systems. In electrostatic units (esu), $k=1$ but charge has different units.

@Triatticus But that only moves the factor of $4\pi$ elsewhere. It arises from the surface area of the unit 2-sphere and cannot really be completely removed. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/810582/174766.

I think of permittivity of free space as a physical constant that reflects the ability of electrical fields to pass through a classical vacuum. I think of it as a physically meaningless constant that reflects nothing more than humans’ definition of SI units.

@VincentThacker yes I'm aware, but the question is specifically about the coulombs constant itself, if it's not present then that needs to be shown how the other quantities in the equation uptake that redefinition. That's why I said things like the charge are redefined here.



What exactly is the rationale behind $4\pi$ in this expression?


Coulomb's law describing the force between two charges
$$F=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Q_1Q_2}{r^2} \tag{1}$$
is closely related to Gauss' law
describing the relation between electric field and charges
$$\epsilon_0 \oint_S\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}=Q_\text{enclosed} \tag{2}$$
In SI units physicists decided to
write Gauss's law (2) with just a single constant $\epsilon_0$.
From this Coulomb's law (1) can be derived with the additional factor $4\pi$.
The essential origin of this $4\pi$ is that a sphere with radius $r$
has a surface area $4\pi r^2$.


How was it exactly determined as a constant of proportionality?
Was it through relatively simple methods like the one used in the Cavendish experiment for determining the value of $G$ ?


The actual value of this constant $\epsilon_0$ cannot be derived
theoretically, but needs to be measured experimentally.
This was first done by experiments similar to the Cavendish one.
But the measurements are much easier here, because electric forces
between charged bodies usually are much stronger than gravitational forces between these.
